# Linker error: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" with CMake project in VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am creating a project x86 DLL target using CMake in Visual Studio (I'm on a 64-bit machine). My CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(MY_HEADERS
    # My files
)

set(MY_SRC
    #My Files
)

add_library(MyLib SHARED ${MY_HEADERS} ${MY_SRC})
target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

set(ALLEGRO_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/include")

if(WIN32)
    file(GLOB ALLEGRO_LIB "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/windows/x86/lib/*.lib")
    add_library(Allegro SHARED IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(Allegro PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${ALLEGRO_DIR}
        INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES ${ALLEGRO_LIB}
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB ${ALLEGRO_LIB}
    )
    target_link_libraries(MyLib PUBLIC Allegro)
    file(GLOB ALLEGRO_DLL "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/packages/allegro5/windows/x86/bin/*.dll")
    foreach(dll ${ALLEGRO_DLL})
        add_custom_command(TARGET MyLib POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            ${dll} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyLib>)
    endforeach()
endif()
```

If I build the above, I get the linker error:

```
unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
```

However, if I changed the DLL to a static library (i.e. add_library(MyLib STATIC ${MY_HEADERS} ${MY_SRC}), there is no linker error. After reading up on the error in similar questions, I added the following to my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
if(WIN32)
    add_definitions(-D_AFXDLL)
    set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 2)
    set_target_properties(MyLib PROPERTIES
        COMPILE_DEFINITIONS _AFXDLL,_UNICODE,UNICODE,_BIND_TO_CURRENT_CRT_VERSION,_BIND_TO_CURRENT_MFC_VERSION
        LINK_FLAGS "/ENTRY:\"wWinMainCRTStartup\""
    )
endif()
```

Right after the line `target_include_directories(MyLib PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")`. However, I continue to get the same linker error with a warning:

```
LNK4258 directive '/ENTRY:mainCRTStartup' not compatible with switch '/ENTRY:wWinMainCRTStartup'; ignored
```

The only thing that seems to resolve this linker error is to add a main.cpp to the DLL project like:

```
int main() {}
```

Why do I need to this for a DLL project and is there a way I can avoid doing this? Note that I'm using the CMake project template from Visual Studio 2019. My CMakeSettings.json file is:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x86-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "cmakeToolchain": "C:/Users/xxx/.vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
      "variables": []
    },
    {
      "name": "x86-Release",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "RelWithDebInfo",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "-v",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "cmakeToolchain": "C:/Users/xxx/.vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "msvc_x86" ],
      "variables": []
    }
  ]
}
```